# SQL code to find values that are common between columns

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with the following information:

```
ID | Color | Fruit      |
1  | Red   | Apple      |
2  | Yellow| Banana     |
3  | Red   | Strawberry |
4  | Red   | Raspberry  |
```

I want to see a list of Fruits that have the same color and also what Color it is. What would the SQL code to return this information be?
Thanks!

Comment: See `GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT(*) > 1` to find the common colors (eg. derived table of single 'Color' column, and one row for "Red"). Then join with the original table to identify the fruit with the common colors. Some databases also have `GROUP_CONCAT` or similar (non-standard, non-normalizing).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You will have a better experience here if you take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62182045/edit) your question with the details needed to create [a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). See [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for tips.

Comment: The first part returning the common "Color" worked. However, I'm not sure how to execute the JOIN. I've seen it being used with different tables. But I'm not sure how to work with it on the same table. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about

```
SELECT COLOR,
       LISTAGG(FRUIT, ',') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY FRUIT) AS FRUITS
  FROM FRUITS
  GROUP BY COLOR
```

This produces the result

```
COLOR   FRUITS
Red     Apple,Raspberry,Strawberry
Yellow  Banana
```

[db<>fiddle here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f3c2cb47162e6697a5260ff4c614e16e)

Comment: Thank you! that worked with Oracle. As for SQL Lite and MySQL this is code that worked. SELECT ID,COLOR,
  GROUP_CONCAT(FRUIT,',')AS FRUIT
  FROM Fruits

Comment: If you need answers for multiple databases you should all the appropriate tags (e.g. the `oracle`, `sqlite`, and `mysql` tags), and mention in the question that you want answers for multiple databases - otherwise people will complain that a question has multiple database tags and won't post answers.